# not able to get CAML query to work as desired

Tags: csom, caml-query, caml

I am trying to get items that have travelDate lesser than 30 days before today.
and then orderby traveldate

But the below query doesn't seem to work

```
<OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name='TravelDate' Ascending='False'/>
            <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'></Value>
    </OrderBy>
<Where>
    <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='TravelDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-30' /></Value>
    </Leq>
</Where>
```

what is wrong with the query? both the  orderby and LEQ doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I haven't enclosed the query with `<View><Query>` tags

```
<View><Query>
<OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name='TravelDate' Ascending='False'/>
            <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='False'></Value>
    </OrderBy>
<Where>
    <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='TravelDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today OffsetDays='-30' /></Value>
    </Leq>
</Where>
</Query></View>
```

the above query worked just fine